# Using XCore generated classes in a war aggregating multiple Maven projects

Tags: war, emf

I have a maven project called `myproject.app`. I also have another project using vaadin and gwt called `myproject.ui` and another project, which is an Xcore-Project converted to Maven called `myproject.model`.

I want to aggregate them all in a war. For this I have a `myproject.war` with a pom declaring the dependencies.

For Vaadin and GWT everthing is working fine as these projects are pure maven projects. The Xcore project gives me headaches because I can't manage to provide the `Plugin Dependencies` declared in this project in the war.

I have tried to add the needed libraries in the pom but I can only get old versions (2.2.3) from Central - the XCore project uses 2.8.*/3.8.*.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to convert the eclipse dependencies (EMF, XCore ...) to maven artifacts using the Maven Tools 4 Eclipse.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/MT4E_FAQ

For professional usage it is necessary to setup a maven repository, I used Nexus with success (if you are developing locally and alone it would be enough to install the artifacts in you local repository).

http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/

You can get it working by setting up a hosted repository with the converted Eclipse artifacts (documented in the mt4e reference) and creating a repository group aggregating the preconfigured maven central proxy and the hosted repository with the eclipse artifacts.

You need to setup your local settings.xml to use the nexus and you're good to go. Eclipse's artifacts are usable via maven coordinates.

Keep the orbit artifacts in mind and design your patch files carefully.